# Google NoCaptcha ReCaptcha

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

If correct, Google introduced Google's NoCaptcha ReCaptcha on december 3th. More information can be found on their [official blog](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.nl/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html).

After reading their story, they refer to their good old ReCaptcha site. Seemingly this has been renewed. So I created an account and started testing. However, I already stumble on two questions that don't seem to be answered on their own site. Google-ing results in old and mostly useless information about the "old" [ReCaptcha module](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html).

1. The thing is not responsive. This seems weird to me. I know I can make it responsive or use a framework or something to do so. But all the HTML / CSS is generated by the plugin itself. Is there some universal solution for this, or Am I missing something?
2. Sometimes clicking the checkbox is all that's needed, but often I still get the old misformed pictures that are still hard to read. In other words, sometimes it looks like nothing has changed. Is this normal, or is this thing not fully released yet?

Comment: I think the system reverts to the hard to read images when it can't tell from the checkbox that your not a bot.

Comment: Wasn't it 60% accuracy that they could tell you're not a bot? In all other cases, you have to enter the CAPTCHA as you normally would.

Comment: From what I understood is that they'd have alternatives for the "hard to read images". E.g. the cat example from the blog link, by selecting all cats. The image is also one of them, but usually a number instead of the standard words.

Comment: Word is they use cookies and searching patterns to determine if you're a bot or not. If they think you're a bot on the page, you'll have that captcha pop up. I get it all the time now when I test it. The images I can't get to load either. I think it's still in beta, but I can't seem to find their old captcha, so it may be released now.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far! If anyone stumbles upon a responsive stylesheet for this, please let me know. Otherwise, I'll create one myself and post it here later on.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the responsive bit?